# value of scope getting undefined using ng-model in controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using a dropdown on which if I select farmers, it would show respective input boxes and if I choose customers, it would show respective input boxes. After selecting value from dropdown and clicking the button i am trying to access the value of input box in controller. But it gets undefined.

```
<div class="container admin-advanced-search-window-container">
    <div class = "col-md-4 form-group dropdown">
        <label style="margin-left: 14rem">Search</label>
        <select  style="margin-left: 20rem;margin-top: -4rem;" kendo-drop-down-list = "typeSelectionList" required ng-model = "type" >
        <option oi-options selected = "true" value = "Farmers">Farmers</option>
            <option oi-options value = "Products">Products</option>
            <option oi-options value = "Customers">Customers</option>
            <option oi-options value = "Trips">Trips</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div id = "Customers" ng-if= "type == 'Customers'">
<div class="container admin-advanced-search-window-container">

    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input style="width: 24rem" type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"
               title="First Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input style="width: 24rem" type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"
               title="Last Name" />
    </div>

</div>
<div class="container admin-advanced-search-window-container">

    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input style="width: 24rem" type="text" name="city" ng-model="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City"
               title="City" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input style="width: 24rem" type="text" name="zipcode" ng-model="zipcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code"
               title="Zip Code" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <button class="advanced-search-button btn btn-primary" type="button"  >Search</button>
</div>
```

```
<div id = "Farmers" ng-if = "type == 'Farmers'">
    <div class="container admin-advanced-search-window-container">

        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input style="width: 24rem" type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="farmerfirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"
                   title="First Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input style="width: 24rem" type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"
                   title="Last Name" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container admin-advanced-search-window-container">

        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input style="width: 24rem" type="text" name="city" ng-model="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City"
                   title="City" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input style="width: 24rem" type="text" name="zipcode" ng-model="zipcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code"
                   title="Zip Code" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button class="advanced-search-button btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click = "advanacedSearchFarmers()">Search</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is my controller's code.

```
$scope.advanacedSearchFarmers = function(){
    var name = $scope.farmerfirstName;
    alert(name);
    var info = {
        "firstName" : $scope.firstName,
     "lastName" : $scope.lastName,
     "city" : $scope.city,
     "zipcode" : $scope.zipcode
    };
    alert("IN ad");
    var promise = AdminService.getFarmersByAdvancedSearch(info);
    promise.then(function(result){

    },function(err){
        alert("Error -"+err);
    });
}
```

When I try to select farmer from dropdown and access its first name , it gives me undefined. Can somebody help me. I am new to angular . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ng-if` creates and destroys temporary local scopes (see [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf))

As a test you could try to change your `ng-if` to `ng-show` and see if the behavior is correct. If so you should refactor your code to avoid sub-scope issues. Just put all your input variables in an object.

Basically just transform situations like this

```
$scope.myInput

<input ng-if="..." ng-model="myInput" />
```

In something like this

```
$scope.Inputs = {};
$scope.Inputs.myInput;

<input ng-if="..." ng-model="Inputs.myInput" />
```

This way the newly `ng-if` created controller will try to search for an already existing `Inputs` object in parent scopes.

Comment: @naigal..Where should write $scope.input ={ }. I am not able to get what you are saying. Can you create a sample.code from above. I am new to this.

Comment: If you create a working JSfiddle I will correct it the way I described :)

Comment: should I use ng-hide instead of ng-if.?.. because in ur solution u have written ng-if

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that on selecting particular option , the respective div section is visible.

Just one small pointer.
In customer & farmer div, the first name property is bind to different scope variable.

```
   ng-model="farmerfirstName" (farmer block)
   ng-model="firstName" (customer block)
```

Hence $scope.firstName will be undefined if farmer block is selected.

Comment: $scope.farmerfirstName gives me undefined even though i am selecting farmer from dropdown